# Invalid Timestamp in woocommerce API

Tags: php, rest, api

We are receiving following error while working on REST API v2 version of WooCommerce. It was working fine when we are retriving data from localhost which is http but now we have uploaded it to the server which is https.

Here is the error which we are getting:

```
stdClass Object
(
[errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [code] => woocommerce_api_authentication_error
                [message] => Invalid Timestamp
            )
    )
)
```

According to the wordpress forum these errors come when the server timestamp and the API timestamp are different. We tried to change the timestamp also but still don't get any luck.

Answer (score 0):

the woocomerce API check if the timestamp is valid:

> A timestamp is valid if it is within 15 minutes of now.

Please, check if the |client time - server time| < 15 minutes.

Check the server - client timezone.